# How can I run an android app inside other android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

I have seen apps like My Jio running their other apps like Jio Saavn and Jio Mart inside it. How can we achieve this?

Comment: You could try making a PWA and implementing the PWA in a web-view inside the app